# Read-only file system error while accessing the files on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, readonly

I have a Ubuntu machine. I am connected to it remotely and getting the following errer:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/testFolder': Read-only file system
```

LIKE WINDOWS, REBOOTING the machine solved this error.

Can someone explain this behaviour to me. I am bit surprised.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer sensibly without knowing *what* file system it is about you're trying to create your `testFolder` on. Consider that also NTFS partitions can be accessed from a Linux-type system...

Answer (score 6):

A filesystem goes into read-only mode when it has consistency issues. It is a way to prevent possible data corruption. Your next would be to take a backup of all important data from this drive since this could also mean that the hard-drive could be on its way out.

When you rebooted the machine, the `/` partition got mounted back in the regular `rw` mode from the read-only it had gone to before rebooting.

You must run an `fsck` on the `/` partition to check for any inconsistancy. Since it is the root partition, I believe you will have to get into rescue mode to run the fsck.